# javascript post request is sending an empty body

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

So i have two post request a signup one which works perfectly fine and a login one which does connect to the server but it sends an empty body. ive been coding for a few hours now so this could easily be a simple mistake but i dont see it. any help would be appreciated.

here is the code:

```
class Auth{

  signUp(user){
    return(

        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/signup`,
          {  headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(user,null,2)
            }).then((res)=>{
              console.log(res)
            }).catch((error)=>{
              console.log(error)
            })

        )
    }

  login(email,password){

    console.log(JSON.stringify({email:email,password:password},null,2))



      return(

            fetch(`http://localhost:3001/login`,
              { header:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },

              method:"POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({email:email,password:password},null,2)

            }).then((res)=>{
                console.log(res)
            }).catch((error)=>{
              console.log(error)
            })

        )

    }


}


export default Auth;
```

server.js

```
    app.post('/signup',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body)
  myDietApi.createUser(req.body)
  .then((data)=>{
    res.send(data)
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
})

app.get('/signup',function(req,res){
  myDietApi.getItemList()
  .then((list)=>{
    res.send(list)
  })

})

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  console.log(req,'line 39')
  myDietApi.requestLogin(req.body)
   .then((user)=>{
    console.log('succes',user)
    res.send(user)
  })
})
```

here this is the server code

Comment: Show us the code where you try to read the body

Comment: ok i added the posts from the server

Comment: you got any ideas?

Comment: No, can't find anything wrong. Did you try making a post from postman and see if you receive the data? Also, check the chrome console and see if the data is being sent from the frontend

Comment: no i did not, thanks for trying

Comment: Well, give it a try. Check the two things I mentioned and come back

Comment: how would i check if the data is being sent from the frontend? i know the request is being received on the backend because my console.logs get triggered

Comment: Open the chrome console and check on the network tab. You should see the outgoing request. What I mentioned about postman will be another way to check where the problem is.

Comment: yeah so it is being sent the request payload contains the information i want to send. ill try postman next